# Javascript, Math: calculate the area of a flat, 2D surface that is situated in 3D

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, polygon, area

I want to be able to calculate the surface area of a 2D polygon of any shape, given a set of 3D vertices. For example, what is the surface area of this figure?

```
var polygon = new Polygon([new Point(0,0,0), new Point(5,8,2), new Point(11,15,7)])
polygon.areaIfPolygonIs3D()
--> some predictable result, no matter how many vertices the polygon has...
```

Keep in mind that polygons only have one surface. They are flat but could be triangle shaped or trapezoid shaped or randomly shaped, and could be floating at a 3D angle... imagine them as pieces of paper turned any which way in 3D space.

What I've tried to do so far is rotate the thing flat, and then use a basic formula for calculating the area of a 2D irregular polygon which is currently working in my code (formula: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Polygon). I had such a hard figuring out how to rotate all the vertices so the polygon lays flat (all "z" values are 0) that I abandoned that path, though I'm open to trying it if someone can get there. (Perhaps there is a bug in Point.rotateBy().)

I can work with Points, and Edges (created with point.to(point)), and Edges have 'theta' (edge.theta()) and 'phi' (edge.phi()).

In any case, if someone can fill in what goes here and help me after a full days effort of trying to relearn all the geometry I forgot from high school, that would be much appreciated!

```
var locatorRho = function(x,y,z) {
  return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
}

var locatorTheta = function(x,y) {
  return Math.atan2(y,x);
};

var locatorPhi = function(x,y,z) {
  return z == 0 ? Math.PI_2 : Math.acos(z/locatorRho(x, y, z));
}

// rotates a point according to another point ('locator'), and their 2D angle ('theta') and 3D angle ('phi')
Point.prototype.rotateBy = function(locator, theta, phi) {
  phi = (phi == undefined ? 0 : phi);
  var relativeX = this.x() - locator.x();
  var relativeY = this.y() - locator.y();
  var relativeZ = this.z() - locator.z();
  var distance = locatorRho(relativeX, relativeY, relativeZ);
  var newTheta = locatorTheta(relativeX, relativeY) + theta;
  var newPhi = locatorPhi(relativeX, relativeY, relativeZ) + phi;
  this._x = locatorX(distance, newTheta, newPhi) + locator.x();
  this._y = locatorY(distance, newTheta, newPhi) + locator.y();
  this._z = locatorZ(distance, newPhi) + locator.z();
}

Polygon.prototype.signedArea = function() {
  var vertices = this.vertices();
  var area = 0;
  for(var i=0, j=1, length=vertices.length; i<length; ++i, j=(i+1)%length) {
    area += vertices[i].x()*vertices[j].y() - vertices[j].x()*vertices[i].y();
  }
  return 0.5*area
}

Polygon.prototype.areaIfPolygonIs2D = function() {
  return Math.abs(rotatedFlatCopy.signedArea())
}

Polygon.prototype.areaIfPolygonIs3D = function() {
    ... help here I am so stuck ...
}

var vertices = [some number of Points, e.g., new Point(x,y,z)]
var polygon = new Polygon(vertices)
var polygon.areaIfPolygonIs3D()
--> result
```

Comment: So you're saying all the points in 3d lie on a plane, and you're interested in the area enclosed by those points in this plane right?  Or are you interested in projected area.

Answer (score 1):

If your polygon plane is not parallel to Z axis, you can calculate area projection with known approach using X and Y coordinates only, then divide result by cosine of angle between Z axis and normal N to that plane

```
 Area = Sum[x1*y2-x2*y1 +...]    ////shoelace formula
 True_Area =  Area / Cos(Angle between N and Z axis)) = 
              Area / DotProduct((N.x,N.y,N.z), (0,0,1)) = 
              Area / N.z 
               ////   if N is normalized (unit)
```

Comment: OZ is direction vector of Z axis. Cosine is for angle - angle between N and OZ. Cosine might be expressed through dot product - it leads to simplification.

Comment: You don't need to get direction of Z axis - it just exists :). Normalized (unit) vector has length 1. What do you know about plane orientation?

Comment: You can calculate normal vector N as vector product of vectors **(vertices[1] - vertices[0])** and **(vertices[2] - vertices[0])**, then find it length, then normalize vector N dividing components by length. Normal vector characterizes plane orientation and it's z-component might be used to find true area, as I wrote.

Comment: what if the normal N is perpendicular to Z ?

Comment: @Mohamed Amine Ouali  Just make projection onto another plane

Answer (score 0):

Use the shoelace formula three times, on the 2D vertices `(X, Y)`, `(Y, Z)` and `(Z, X)`. The desired area is given by `√Axy²+Ayz²+Azx²` (provided the polygon is flat).